Unable to use the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter
this is my build.gradle PROJECT LEVEL:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.realm.gradle.plugin)
    }
}

and this is my build.gradle MODULE LEVEL:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    id("realm-android")

}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.todoappv2"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.todoappv2"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.realm.gradle.plugin)




    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)

}

After I implement this dependencies, why I still cannot use the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter?
Did I forgot to implement some more of the dependencies to use it?
I am quite new to the Realm Database so I hope someone can help me to resolve my doubts :(!!!!
